# graphene django relay: Relay transform error

Tags: python, django, reactjs, graphql, relay

Being very new to GraphQL, I have a graphene django implementation of a server with two models, following rather closely the [graphene docs' example](http://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/tutorial.html).

In graphiql, I can do this, and get a result back.

[image]

Following another [relay tutorial](https://medium.com/@clayallsopp/relay-101-building-a-hacker-news-client-bb8b2bdc76e6#.vephqa6ww), I'm intending to render the result of this query on screen.

My attempt looks like this:

```
class Note extends Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div> {this.props.store.title} </div>
    )
  }
}

Note = Relay.createContainer(Note, {
  fragments: {
    store: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment on Query {
        note(id: "Tm90ZU5vZGU6MQ==") {
          id
          title
        }
      }
    `
  }
});

class NoteRoute extends Relay.Route {
  static routeName = 'NoteRoute';
  static queries = {
    store: Component => {

      return Relay.QL`
      query {
        ${Component.getFragment('store')}
      }
    `},
  };
}
```

My browser's console shows the following error:

``` Uncaught Error: Relay transform error ``There are 0 fields supplied to the query named `Index`, but queries must have exactly one field.`` in file `/Users/.../src/index.js`. Try updating your GraphQL schema if an argument/field/type was recently added. ```

I've been trying to figure it out on my own with limited success.

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think Relay doesn't allow fragments `on Query`. You need one and exactly one field on the query in your `NoteRoute`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @stubailo for pointing me in the right direction. I made some adjustments, and now have a minimum example running like this:

```
NoteList = Relay.createContainer(NoteList, {
  fragments: {
    store: () => Relay.QL`
      fragment N on NoteNodeConnection {
        edges {
          node{
            id
            title
            note
          }
        }
      }
    `
  }
});

class NoteRoute extends Relay.Route {
  static routeName = 'NoteRoute';
  static queries = {
    store: Component => {

      return Relay.QL`
      query {
        notes {
          ${Component.getFragment('store')}
        }
      }
    `},
  };
}
```